# Reinstalling Mac Mini

Tags: macos, mac

Basically, I bought a used Mac Mini and I had to reinstall it. Trying to do so following a tutorial and it told me to boot into the recovery, remove the partition and then use the Reinstall Mac OS X option.

I did that, entered the details for the Apple ID I created to do this and it just shows me this: ([http://i.imgur.com/5jrNiId.jpg](https://i.imgur.com/5jrNiId.jpg))
[image]

Is there any way around this? I don't have access to the previous owner's Apple ID and I created mine just to do this. The partition is gone so there's no way to restore it to that either.

Comment: & did you go review your information?

Comment: When you click Review - what happens? (It makes sense if you just made a brand new Apple ID, you might have to add some details to make the account active.)

Comment: Oops, sorry. When I click Review the entire thing closes, putting me back into the 'main menu' where I have to enter my details again (doesn't even automatically pop up the login window immediately). The Apple ID is filled with all the details it asked for and all the extra details I coild find in the Apple ID website